# BigQuery Wildcard using TABLE_DATE_RANGE()

Tags: google-bigquery

Great news about the new table wildcard functions this morning! Is there a way to use TABLE_DATE_RANGE() on tables that include date but no prefix?

I have a dataset that contains tables named YYYYMMDD (no prefix). Normally I would query like so:

```
SELECT foo 
FROM [mydata.20140319],[mydata.20140320],[mydata.20140321] 
LIMIT 100
```

I tried the following but I'm getting an error:

```
SELECT foo
FROM 
  (TABLE_DATE_RANGE(mydata., 
                TIMESTAMP('2014-03-19'), 
                TIMESTAMP('2015-03-21')))
LIMIT 100
```

as well as:

```
SELECT foo
FROM 
  (TABLE_DATE_RANGE(mydata, 
                TIMESTAMP('2014-03-19'), 
                TIMESTAMP('2015-03-21')))
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Where have you read about these today?

Comment: @Pentium10 The release notes: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/release-notes#03252014

Comment: @Pentium10 announced via the "BigQuery Announce" Google Group as well - worth subscribing to: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/bigquery-announce

Comment: How do we handle the same scenario with standard SQL where there are no prefixes to the table name?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The underlying bug here has been fixed as of 2015-05-14. You should be able to use `TABLE_DATE_RANGE` with a purely numeric table name. You'll need to end the dataset in a '.' and enclose the name in brackets, so that the parser doesn't complain. This should work:

```
SELECT foo
FROM 
  (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([mydata.], 
                TIMESTAMP('2014-03-19'), 
                TIMESTAMP('2015-03-21')))
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: I get a "Timestamp evaluation: result is NaN or NULL" error when I follow this approach .

Answer (score 8):

Note: The underlying bug has been fixed, please see my other answer.
Original response left for posterity (since the workaround should still work, in case you need it for some reason)

Great question. That should work, but it doesn't currently. I've filed an internal bug. In the meantime, a workaround is to use the `TABLE_QUERY` function, as in:

```
SELECT foo
FROM (
  TABLE_QUERY(mydata,
              "TIMESTAMP(table_id) BETWEEN "
               + "TIMESTAMP('2014-03-19') "
               + "AND TIMESTAMP('2015-03-21')"))
```

Comment: what's the advantage to have data tables per days?

Comment: A lot of users like to partition their data by day for easier table management (old tables can be deleted) and they can run lower-cost queries (since you only need to query over the days you need).

Comment: is there a way to automatically create repeating schema based on fly, or on first insert? Otherwise you end up, that you need to create the schema for each partition.

Answer (score 6):

Note that with [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) support in BigQuery, you can use [`_TABLE_SUFFIX`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#the_table_date_range_functions), instead of `TABLE_QUERY`. For example:

```
SELECT foo
FROM `mydata_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20140319' AND '20150321'
```

Also check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37664185/is-there-an-equivalent-of-table-wildcard-functions-in-bigquery-with-standard-sql) for more about BigQuery standard SQL.

Comment: This answer is frivolous, it's not clear if 'mydata' is a dataset name or the table name , in both cases it does not work in standard SQL with BigQuery.

Comment: I am using `mydata` as that was used in the question. It refers to the table id and in standard SQL normally is in the format `project_id.dataset_id.table_id`.