# Query with Table Value Function cannot be saved as view

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm attempting to make a view that uses a table value function to provide a roll up of a bunch of daily tables however when I attempt to save the view I always get an error. Below are a couple variations I've tried and the errors each produced. All of these are working queries that can be ran and return the expected results.

Call our dataset `mydataset` and table names are of the form `user_yyyyMMdd`

```
SELECT 
 * 
FROM 
(TABLE_QUERY(mydataset,
              'table_id CONTAINS "user_"'))

---------------------
Failed to create view. Table name cannot be resolved: dataset name is missing.


---------------------
SELECT 
 *
FROM 
(TABLE_DATE_RANGE(mydataset.user_, 
                TIMESTAMP('2014-10-01'), 
                TIMESTAMP('2014-10-14')))
 ----------------------
 Failed to create view. Not Found: Table myproject:mydataset.user_
```

For the date range query there is a table for every day in the range, inclusive. Another question indicated a bug with resolved queries in TVF's while that might explain why my first example doesn't work, the second (as far as I understand) has no query in TBF, it simply uses a TBF. Is there a bug around creating views that use TBF's? Is there something wrong with my query? It applicable is there a work around available?

Comment: possible duplicate of [BigQuery Wildcard using TABLE\_DATE\_RANGE()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22641894/bigquery-wildcard-using-table-date-range)

Comment: yeah I'm for closing as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this one 
[Use of TABLE_DATE_RANGE function in Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681475/use-of-new-table-date-range-function-in-new-views)

And the open request in the issue tracker @

Comment: Thank you that pretty much answers my questions.