# Google BigQuery using TABLE_DATE_RANGE() Error

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using TABLE_DATE_RANGE() is a BigQuery query and I get an error

```
SELECT distinct visitId, fullVisitorId 
  FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([project.view.ga_sessions_],
        TIMESTAMP('2021-09-12'),
        TIMESTAMP('2021-09-13')) )
```

[image]

> Error running query Syntax error: Expected keyword JOIN but got ")" at
> [4:34]

I've used [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30244113/10652174) as the basis for my query so where am I going wrong?

Comment: try `SELECT distinct visitId, fullVisitorId 
  FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([project:view.ga_sessions_],
        TIMESTAMP('2021-09-12'),
        TIMESTAMP('2021-09-13'))` and make sure you are in Legacy Mode (not in Standard SQL) - you can check this in Query Settings Panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below corrected example and make sure you are in Legacy Mode (not in Standard SQL) - you can check this in Query Settings Panel

```
SELECT distinct visitId, fullVisitorId    
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([project:view.ga_sessions_],         
  TIMESTAMP('2021-09-12'),         
  TIMESTAMP('2021-09-13'))
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there a way to something similar using Standard SQL?

Comment: sure. check out [Wildcard tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/wildcard-table-reference)